# Frame where the relative speed between $\vec v$ and $\vec u$ is greatest?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

I am doing a practice problem which basically can simplified down to:

> Find the frame where $|(\vec v-\vec u)|$ is greatest.

This question can be done via a long winded algebraic analysis, but I was wondering if their was a quick way of doing this? Via intuition I would guess the answer is that the frame is where $\vec v'=-\vec u'$ but this is based on nothing more then intuition.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your intuition is right from considering the simple case when both frames are moving at nearly the speed of light, then the maximum is clearly $2c-\epsilon$. The algebra doesn't look that hard to me.

Answer (score 0):

An idea using the 1d case:

Let S be your own rest frame, and S', S" the frames moving at $v$ and $u$ respectively relative to S. Let $u'$ be the velocity of S" relative to S'. Assume $u'$ is kept fixed, and look at $u-v$ as $v$ varies, in S.

If both S' and S" move in the same direction relative to S, $u-v$ can only decrease as $v$ increases since in this case both $u$ and $v$ approach the speed of light. So to maximizes $u-v$, $u$ and $v$ must have opposite directions.

Suppose we find $v<0$ and $u>0$ such that $u-v$ is maximal, but $v\neq -u$. If we redo the procedure for $u' \rightarrow -u'$, the values for $v$ and $u$ will change signs to $-v$, $-u$, but then interchanging frames S' and S" shows that this situation must be exactly equivalent to the original one provided $-v$ and $-u$ are also interchanged. Wherefrom we get that $v = -u$ and $u-v = 2u$.